# How to secure wcslen function and other similar functions

Tags: c, winapi

According http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax%28v=vs.80%29.aspx,

wcslen function and other similar functions incur a potential threat brought about by a buffer overrun problem.

Should I worry, and if yes, how can I use these function safely?

Answer (score 0):

You should worry about `wcslen` as much as you should worry about e.g. `strlen`. These functions expect a C string, i.e. a pointer to a sequence of characters which is terminated by a null byte (0x00). If you don't include a null byte, they will happily continue traversing the memory (running beyond the limits of any buffer you pass to them):

```
const char s1[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' }; /* Array of three characters, no null-terminator */
strlen( s1 );                        /* Unsafe, anything may happen. */

const char s2[] = "abc";             /* Array of three characters plus null-terminator */
strlen( s2 );                        /* Safe, returns '3'. */
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that `strlen_s` and similar secure functions can be used to prevent this problem if the size of the buffer is known.